# Populating row numbers with Field calculator using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, attribute-table, qgsexpression

I have the following code, which is creating a new column called "group" without issue, but not populating it with a row number 1-*n*, as I'm intending it to.

```
pv = layer.dataProvider()
pv.addAttributes([QgsField('group', QVariant.Double)])

layer.updateFields()
expression = QgsExpression('@row_number')

context = QgsExpressionContext()
context.appendScopes(QgsExpressionContextUtils.globalProjectLayerScopes(layer))

with edit(layer):
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        context.setFeature(f)
        f['group'] = expression.evaluate(context)
        layer.updateFeature(f)
```

I do not get an error, it just prints a bunch of null values instead of 1-*n*.

[image]

Is anything popping out as wrong? I followed a tutorial verbatim, and just substituted `@area` for `@row_number`, which is the expression I need in this case.
I replaced `@row_number` with `$id` and it worked, but I'd still like to know why `@row_number` doesn't.

Comment: You may find this thread https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/309628/how-to-add-a-rownumber-in-qgis-3-using-python relevant, moreover, you may try using the `@row_number` via the `'qgis:refactorfields'` algorithm, see this https://sisteme-ig.com/questions/15146/qgis-refactorfields-no-acepta-row-number-como-expresion (Spanish). Hopefully @xunilk can pay attention at your issue.